# Comparing nls model with different sample size

Tags: r, nls

I'm running a nls.lm models on some data.  It's a first order curve: Y1~Cr*(1 - exp(-Kr*X1)) which fits my data well up until a certain value of X1 when the model and data start to diverge.  I want to run my model on incremental increases in my data (i.e. X1[1:25], X1[1:26], X1[1:27]......X1[1:N]) and compare the models to find how much data creates the best fit.  Is there a way to compare these models?  I was thinking AIC but that [changes with sample size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94718/model-comparison-with-aic-based-on-different-sample-size)

Comment: This question would probably be more suited over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I've just posted there